# how to invite my friends to my group using facebook api 2.1

Tags: vb.net, facebook, members

For inviting friends to a group I use below code

```
Dim fb = New FacebookClient (TockenAccess) 
Dim parameters As Object = New ExpandoObject () 
parameters.member = "1000048247037551" 
Await fb.PostTaskAsync ("/ 1387586938758287 / members" parameters)
```

but they return the error.

> An exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: (OAuthException - #3) (#3) Unknown method
>
> error message : {"(OAuthException - #3) (#3) Unknown method"}

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't place spaces between the slashes and the group-id token.

Try using following code:

```
Dim fb = New FacebookClient (TockenAccess) //this should spell TokenAccess btw.
Dim parameters As Object = new ExpandoObject ()
parameters.member = "1000048247037551"
Await fb.PostTaskAsync ("/1387586938758287/members" parameters)
```

Read more in the [official group member api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/members)

Comment: still did not work, is what I'm forced to create the group by the application?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes. This is also documented.

Comment: Apps can only invite people to groups **created by that app itself!** This is documented behaviour!